# Is building a Haskell function from a dictionary (Data.Map.Strict.Map) inefficient?

Tags: dictionary, haskell

I have a function which converts a Map k v (from [Data.Map.Strict](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) in [containers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers)) to a regular function (k -> v). The code is of the following form:

```
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as Map

funcFromMap :: (Ord k) => Map.Map k v -> k -> v
funcFromMap map = (\k -> fromMaybe (error "error message") $ Map.lookup k map)
```

When I run my application with time profiling, this function takes the top spot at ~40% total time. This is surprising, because it only gets called on the result of a fold that performs dynamic programming computations that I would expect to be significantly more expensive than `funcFromMap`. Is writing a function of the above form generally a bad idea for some reason?

p.s: The rest of my code is designed to avoid lookups for keys that aren't in the map, so I think this implementation should at least be safe.

Comment: How much of that 40% is spent on `Map.lookup` itself?

Comment: Also, wrapping `Map.lookup` just to turn a total function into a partial function seems like a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: "Please debug the performance problem in my code" isn't a great question to start with. But without "and here's my code" it's hopeless even if somebody got excited by it.

Comment: This is a re-implementation of the standard partial function `Data.Map.(!)`.

Comment: I'm aware of Data.Map.(!), but I wanted to be able to write a custom error message. The actual implementation I'm using takes a bit more care to provide diagnostic info in the event of a lookup that returns Nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you aren't turning a `Map` into a function.  You're turning a function (namely `Map.lookup`) into another function.  Haskell programming is all about turning functions into other functions, so if that was inefficient, we'd all be in a lot of trouble!

In short, there's nothing wrong with `funcFromMap` (except that it already exists as the function `(!)`, as @chi pointed out), and there's no reason it should be inefficient.

First, make sure you're reading the "individual" column instead of the "inherited" column in the profile output.  The "individual" column gives the time actually spent in the function itself.

If the "individual" column genuinely says 40%, then what's happened is that `lookup` has been inlined into your `funcFromMap`, and for some reason the actual map lookups are very expensive in your application.  I think we'd need to see a minimal example that illustrates the problem to say why.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate the info about individual / inherited in the time profile output, that is new info for me. With that said, that 40% number did come from the individual column. I will have to figure out why my lookups are taking so much time.